# CSS Sticky Footer in ASP.NET page

Tags: asp.net, css, sticky-footer

I've used the sticky footer CSS technique on static pages in the past without issue. However, I'm now designing my first big ASP project and for the life of me I can't get it to work.

I'm following [these instructions (How to Use the Sticky Footer Code)](http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/using-sticky-footer-code.html) and have added the `<form>` element to the `html, body, form, #wrap {height: 100%;}` statement. I've also played with all variations (I think) of having the form element inside & outside my `div#main` and `div#wrapper` all to no avail.

Note: My controls only contain header and footer divs.

Any help massively appreciated!!

Here's the CSS:

```
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 font-family: Calibri, Arial, Sans-Serif;
 }

body {
background-color: #646362;
color: white;
}

/* centre all content on page */
div#wrap {
width: 900px; 
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
}

/*link styling*/

a:link {
color: white;
}

a:visited {color: white;
}

a:link.SortText 
{
color:#fde801;
text-decoration: none;
}

a:visited.SortText
{
color:#fde801;
}

/*remove filter text style*/

a:link.RemoveFilterText
{
color: white;
font-size:small;
font-style:italic;
}

th a:link, td a:link, td a:visited 
{
color: #fde801;
}


/*Remove borders from link images*/
a img 
{
border: none;
}

img#rss_icon
{
margin: 3px 0px 2px 10px;
}

/*ridelist sort text style*/
.SortText 
{
color: #fde801;
font-size:small;
font-style:italic;
}


/*table styles*/
table {
width: 900px;
border-collapse: collapse;
}

th 
{
color: White;
border: none;
text-align: center;
padding-bottom: 20px;
}

table
{ 
border: none;
}

td 
{
padding: 2px;
color: White;
/*height: 1.5em;*/
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;
border: none;
border-right: 1px solid gray;
border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
}


/*Details View Table Styling
******
******
******
*/

/*details view image margin to account for no column header title*/

table#DetailsView1 img 
{
margin-left: -73px;
}

table#DetailsView1 td 
{
vertical-align:top;
}

#footer
{
color: #fde801;
/*margin-top: 2em;
margin-bottom: 0.5em;*/
text-align: center;
/*font-size: small;*/
}


/*CSS Sticky footer - to make footer always stay at bottom of page*/
html, body, form, #wrap {height: 100%;}

#wrap {min-height: 100%;}

#main {overflow:auto;
padding-bottom: 50px;}  /* must be same height as the footer */

#footer {position: relative;
margin-top: -50px; /* negative value of footer height */
height: 50px;
clear:both;}'
```

And the ASP:

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="ridelist2.aspx.vb"      Inherits="ridelist2" %>

<%@ Register src="webcontrols/WebUserControl.ascx" tagname="WebUserControl" tagprefix="uc1" %>

<%@ Register src="webcontrols/footer.ascx" tagname="footer" tagprefix="uc2" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="StyleSheet.css" />
<title>Ride List</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrap">


<uc1:WebUserControl ID="WebUserControl1" runat="server" />

<div id="main">  
<form id="form1" runat="server">
Filter by location:

<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="detachedSQL" appendDataBoundItems="true" DataTextField="prevride_location" DataValueField="prevride_location">
</asp:DropDownList>
&nbsp;
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Filter" BorderColor="#FDE801" Width="56px" />
&nbsp;<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" CssClass="RemoveFilterText" 
NavigateUrl="~/ridelist2.aspx">Remove filter</asp:HyperLink>
<br />
<br />
<span class="SortText">Sort by clicking column headers.</span><br />
<br />



<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowSorting="True"    AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="prevride_id" 
    DataSourceID="detachedSQL">

<Columns>
<asp:BoundField DataField="prevride_organiser" HeaderText="Organiser" 
SortExpression="prevride_organiser" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="prevride_location" HeaderText="Location" 
SortExpression="prevride_location" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="prevride_date" HeaderText="Ride Date" 
SortExpression="prevride_date" DataFormatString="{0:d}" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="prevride_rating" HeaderText="Rating" 
SortExpression="prevride_rating" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="prevride_shortdesc" HeaderText="Info" 
SortExpression="prevride_shortdesc" />
<asp:ImageField DataImageUrlField="prevride_thumb">
</asp:ImageField>
<asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="prevride_id" 
DataNavigateUrlFormatString="details2.aspx?prevride_id={0}" 
Text="View Details" />
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="detachedSQL" runat="server" 
ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [prevrides]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
</form>
</div><!--end of main div-->
</div><!--end of wrap div--> 


<uc2:footer ID="footer1" runat="server" />

</body>
</html>



<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head><link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="StyleSheet.css" /><title>
Ride List
</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrap">






<div id="header">    

<a href="rss.aspx">
<img id="rss_icon" alt="View RSS Feed" 
        src="images/icon_rss_thumb.png" /></a><br />
<img alt="Welcome to CycleCal.com" src="images/header.png"  
        style="width: 900px; height: 200px" id="headerimg" />

</div>
<!--end header div-->





<div id="main">  
<form name="form1" method="post" action="ridelist2.aspx" id="form1">
<div>
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTTARGET" id="__EVENTTARGET" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTARGUMENT" id="__EVENTARGUMENT" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="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 mSW5qkA1mWcLJ1JSr37WzmwsS2sE7w/thtDhfrcW9zudUjBVeo8Tha8q3JZGFl7f5sreLaspHC4THlH45VWJ6Oc7BpR    eJuRHSXtYdnWfywufoatqo=" />
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var theForm = document.forms['form1'];
if (!theForm) {
theForm = document.form1;
}
function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {
    theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
    theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
    theForm.submit();
}
}
//]]>
</script>


<div>

<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATEENCRYPTED" id="__VIEWSTATEENCRYPTED" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTVALIDATION" id="__EVENTVALIDATION" value="fqkvl0aS2shRg5ls6E0+sLArVuW5gD24KKAtqJQctUm8/fB4bHh6/GFebvtfoKFz0YKS4urB+2A4XW8zX8hfDa/B4I7r2LFpMmyYVA/XSMXhSm5eFj/gknffPX145m6u2kPwfYkxReXgwSsM9xi/X3+mbQy02f1fyiLjrFekNgHbeCcCCBEUUSf8VpXnwOIS" />
</div>
        Filter by location:

        <select name="DropDownList1" id="DropDownList1">
<option value="Alps, France">Alps, France</option>
<option value="Land&#39;s End, UK">Land&#39;s End, UK</option>
<option value="Monmouth, UK">Monmouth, UK</option>
<option value="Bristol, UK">Bristol, UK</option>

</select>
```

Remove filter
    
    
    Sort by clicking column headers.

```
<div>
<table cellspacing="0" rules="all" border="1" id="GridView1" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
<tr>
<th scope="col"><a href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;GridView1&#39;,&#39;Sort$prevride_organiser&#39;)">Organiser</a>
</th>
<th scope="col"><a href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;GridView1&#39;,&#39;Sort$prevride_location&#39;)">Location</a>
</th>
<th scope="col"><a href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;GridView1&#39;,&#39;Sort$prevride_date&#39;)">Ride Date</a>
</th>
<th scope="col"><a href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;GridView1&#39;,&#39;Sort$prevride_rating&#39;)">Rating</a>
</th>
<th scope="col"><a href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;GridView1&#39;,&#39;Sort$prevride_shortdesc&#39;)">Info</a>
</th>
<th scope="col">&nbsp;</th><th scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Paul Goring</td><td>Alps, France</td><td>24/10/2009</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td><td>Passportes du Soleil event</td><td><img src="images/alps1s.jpg" style="border-width:0px;" /></td><td><a href="details2.aspx?prevride_id=1">View Details</a>
</td> 
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Gareth Roulston</td><td>Land&#39;s End, UK</td>
<td>25/05/2011</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>Start of our LEJOG</td><td><img src="images/landsend1s.jpg" style="border-width:0px;" /></td><td><a href="details2.aspx?prevride_id=2">View Details</a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>John Whittle</td><td>Monmouth, UK</td><td>28/05/2011</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td><td>Day 3 of our LEJOG - all welcome to join us.</td><td><img src="images/monmouth1s.jpg" style="border-width:0px;" /></td><td><a href="details2.aspx?prevride_id=3">View Details</a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Jordan Lambert</td><td>Bristol, UK</td><td>27/05/2011</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>Cornwall to Malpas, overnight in Bristol</td><td><img src="images/severnbridge1s.jpg" style="border-width:0px;" /></td><td><a href="details2.aspx?prevride_id=4">View Details</a></td> 
</tr>
</table>
</div>

</form>
</div><!--end of main div-->

</div><!--end of wrap div--> 




<!--footer section-->
<div id="footer">
&copy CycleCal.com 2011 | Design <a href="http://www.garethroulston.co.uk">www.garethroulston.co.uk</a>
</div><!--end of footer div-->

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It is hard to tell without seeing the rendered HTML.  Have you verified that the markup generated by the ASP page is what you are expecting?  Specifically, that your footer div has the correct ID?  ASP.NET will generate the ID if your footer div tag has a runat="server" tag.  You can also use the developer tools in your web browser to inspect your HTML elements and view what styles are being applied to your footer div.

Comment: Hi, I've added my HTML output to the question...I can't see any issues with it but I must be missing something somewhere??

Answer (score 1):

do you need this footer to appear on all pages? Look at using master pages and putting the footer in the master template

Comment: Will do...however, I'm still stuck with a footer that is hovering away from the bottom of the screen and that also overlaps my GridView when the browser window is resized to be smaller than the GridView.

Comment: Is your footer a certain color - background that is. One option if you cant get it to sit flush on the bottom is to make you background the same color as your footer and then your content area white. This way it wont matter if your footer does not sit on the bottom

Comment: This does not really seem to be an attempt to answer the question; sticky footers can be done without needing to fake it to look like it. Using a Master page is probably a good idea, but isn't really related.

Comment: I agree, I know there must be a way to get this sticky footer to work but can't see where the bug is. Andrew - can you help?